# Android Debugging Mode Performance

Tags: android, performance, debugging

Just out of curiosity. Logically thinking, does Android debugging mode slows down the performance of Android devices?

How can I prove to users that Android debugging does or does not slow down the Android?

P.S.: I need **specific answer** and **reliable source** to how can I prove it?

Comment: Any ideas??? Assume the users are not programming experts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Attaching a debugger almost always slows down the performance.  The best way to prove any performance related argument is always to run some tests.  Set some timers in your code and gather the data empirically.  Then you'll know not only which way is faster but by exactly how much.

For a 'specific answer' - measure and your tests will be the 'reliable source'

Comment: Any ideas how can I set some timers in my code and gather the data empirically? @spatulamania

Comment: @Ezylryb You can surround the pieces of code you wish to time with calls to `System.nanoTime()`.  Then calculate the difference to compute the elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

Run the application with and without debugging and show the execution time difference. It's best to use an app that simply opens, does some calculations or something then exits that way there's no user error in interacting with it.

Comment: Any ideas how can I do the calculation on how fast the application runs? @Jesus Ramos